# Method call that call method from other object

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if it's possible to otain such behaviour where method call of one object will call method of another object.

```
public class Example
{
    public void DoSomething() { /*BASICALLY NOTHING*/ }
}

public class Engine
{
    public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("bleee"); }

    static void Main()
    {
        Example e = new Example();
        Engine eng = new Engine();

        e.DoSomething = eng.DoSomething;
    }
}
```

My `Example` object is exactly dummy object, but I would like to use this class as base class and build on top of it something more fancy.

So `e.DoSomething()` should call method from `eng.DoSomething()`. I can't use inheritance or pass `Engine` object to `Example` as argument.

Is it possible? How to achieve that? Is such approach used somewhere?

Comment: I sense delegates in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in the way you describe, but you can do it with delegates.

```
public class Example
{
    public Action DoSomething {get; set;}
}

public class Engine
{
    public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("bleee"); }

    static void Main()
    {
        Example e = new Example();
        Engine eng = new Engine();

        e.DoSomething = eng.DoSomething;
    }
}
```

Now you can say `e.DoSomething()` and it will call via the delegate by calling the getter and then calling the returned action.

Comment: would it be possible to do this with reflection or some kind of IL rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection we can do the method call with same type info. But other types method is not possible. I think so.